# Delphi vcl.net applications and decompilation

Tags: .net, delphi, obfuscation, vcl

.net applications can be decompiled easily . But with the use obfuscator it can be made harder.

My application is a Delphi for .net vcl (delphi for .net 2006) application. My problem is: 
Is my application also in the above category (can be decompiled easily) or it is hard as decompiling a win32 application

I have not yet used obfuscator . I want to know whether my application need obfuscator or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should obfuscate your code if your concerned about decompiling.

All .NET applications can be decompiled.   VCL.NET applications are no exception.
Tools are smart enough to even decompile an application to another language.   It's not perfect but it does work.

Although it has been awhile since I have used that product, I am fairly sure it shipped with a obfuscation tool.

Comment: Then can we decompile(using decompiling tools like reflector) it to c# and recompile it with c# (without using delphi)

Comment: So it may be a easy way to convert a delphi application into a c# application

Comment: @vibeeshanRC, it could be an easy way to translate the program logic, but it would still be a VCL.NET application. C# programmers wouldn't know the libraries, wouldn't have a visual designer, and would need to buy a Delphi license before they could redistribute the VCL.NET libraries that the app requires. So it's a big stretch to say it's an "easy way to convert a delphi application into a c# application"...

Comment: No, Delphi for .Net produces some constructions that can't be recompiled in C# without changes. For example it produces Meta classes with $ in their name. Of course the general meaning of the code isn't difficult to read. Why not give it a try? You have Delphi , C# and know about reflector.